# Generate endpoint (controller/action) in custom module to get customer info using token in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i want  generate an Endpoint(controller/action) in custom module.The input to this endpoint is going to be an “access_token” and the output response must be something like

```
    {"first_name": "xyz", "last_name": "xyz", "email":"xyz@gmail.com","uid": "12jlkd1k2", ‚phone_no‛:’ +1 xxx-xxx-xxxx’};
```

It is possible to create such type of controller without using magneto api service's.please help me to find best way or solution.

Comment: You can use **Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array)**  inside your endpoint (controller/action)..

Comment: This is not issue to convert result in to json.i want retrieve customer data  using token.i will pass token to this controller action then controller action return the above result.i can`t understand how retrieve data using token in magneto.i will search many more but i can`t find proper solution.this controller/action used to validation of magneto user.

Comment: I'm not sure about token...it would be better if you explain in details

Comment: token is unique which can identify user.